# Jenkins-X "ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node"

Tags: github, jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to set up an Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS using Jenkins-X. After setting up the cluster, when I try to build the application I get the below error:

```
Branch indexing
08:55:40 Connecting to using demoawsgaurav/****** (API Token for acccessing Git service inside pipelines)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from ea0a2e0f0dd9737d74205137444e79d3315e4e36
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/-huggerprairie-production_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential jx-pipeline-git-github-github
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git
 > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/-huggerprairie-production_master # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials API Token for acccessing github.com Git service inside pipelines
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/demoawsgaurav/environment-huggerprairie-production.git
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials API Token for acccessing https://github.com Git service inside pipelines
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
Checking out Revision ea0a2e0f0dd9737d74205137444e79d3315e4e36 (master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ea0a2e0f0dd9737d74205137444e79d3315e4e36
Commit message: "Add environment configuration"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Environment)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Update Environment)
Stage "Update Environment" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: Node is not a Kubernetes node: 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help...